# Sending and Receiving data from virtual Com port - C#

Tags: c#, windows, embedded, usb, uart

How can I send and receive data from the virtual com port.
Is it the same as rx/tx'ing data from a com port on windows.On the device manager I see my device under Ports(COM & LPT) listed as **ABC device virtual COM port(COM18)**.
I have the full access to the device firmware.I see that it is sending data on Uart in the device firmware at the rate of 921600 (which is clearly higher than the highest baud rate for UART - 115200) and  connected to mini-b usb cable to Host(Windows).From where can I start - APIs for C# - COM or virtual Com (if any) or anything else.
Thanks in advance

Comment: [this?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Denis : Is Serial Port same as Virtual com port?I tried the code you put in the link but on the host even though it says it sends the data but on device I cant see the data or break point hitting on the data reception code.

Comment: If it lists the virtual com port when you enumerate the ports, it should be able to work with that. Isn't a virtual com port a device driver simulating a com port on top of the HAL?